# Need guidance on re-writing this query

Tags: hadoop, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

Current Scenario => We have a query which we are running on our prod cluster.
this query selects just 3 fields from a join between 1 table and ( nested way of join )another huge table and then performs a groupby at the end but runs for 2 hours on production and it hits one huge table in that join

Query  :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mstr_wrk.final_acct_data 
    SELECT
       a0,
       a1,
       a2,
       a3 
    FROM
                   (
                  SELECT
                 t1.a0 as a0 
                  FROM
                 (
                    SELECT
                       t1.a0 as a0 
                    FROM
                       (
                      SELECT
                         CAST(t1.acct_id AS STRING) as a0 
                      FROM
                         mstr_wrk.cust_xref t1
                       )
                       t1 
                    GROUP BY
                       t1.a0
                 )
                 t1
               )
       tab1 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              (
             SELECT
              a0,
              a1,
              a2 
             FROM
                (
                   SELECT
        (
                  CASE
                     WHEN
                    1 = t1.a1 
                     THEN
                    t1.a0 
                     ELSE
                    CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) 
                  END
        ) as a0, UDFcalldate('TRUNC', UDFcalldate('ADD_TO_DATE', 
                  (
                     CASE
                    WHEN
                       1 = t1.a1 
                    THEN
                       t1.a0 
                    ELSE
                       CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) 
                     END
                  )
        , 'D', - 1), 'DD') as a1 
                   FROM
                  (
                     SELECT
                    MAX(t1.a0) as a0,
                    MAX(t1.a1) as a1 
                     FROM
                    (
                       SELECT
                          load_audit.run_ts as a0,
                          1 as a1 
                       FROM
                          mstr_wrk.load_audit 
                       WHERE
                          val_name = 'card_stg'
                    )
                    t1
                  )
                  t1
                )
                tab4 
                JOIN
                   (
                  SELECT
                     CAST(t1.acct_cd AS STRING) as a0,
                     CAST(t1.h_acct_cd AS STRING) as a1,
                     CAST(t1.acct_num AS STRING) as a2,
                     CAST(t1.load_dt AS TIMESTAMP) as a3,
                     t1.ts as a4 
                  FROM
                     mstr_work.acct_crd t1
                   )
                 tab3 
             WHERE
                (
                   tab4.a0 < tab3.a4
                )
                AND 
                (
                   tab4.a1 <= tab3.a3
                )
              )
          tab2 
          ON (tab1.a0 = tab2.a1) 
    WHERE
       1 = 
       (
          CASE
         WHEN
            tab1.a0 IS NULL 
         THEN
            1 
         ELSE
            0 
          END
       )
    GROUP BY
       tab2.a0, tab2.a1, tab2.a2
```

What I tried - 
I tried to enable CBO and vectorization along with ppd but no luck
I dont see any small table here so cant try map side join
One of the joins, which looks like a cross join can be translated to inner join
but is there anyway i can try CTE here

Request - 
Kindly guide how can i fix it
is there any better way to rewrite this query.

Comment: There are a lot of things that don't make any sense... e.g. Writing `1 = (CASE WHEN tab1.a0 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, when that is equivalent to `tab1.a0 IS NULL`. You also have a `GROUP BY` with no aggregations, selecting only the `GROUP BY` variable. Is your query not in simplest form for some reason?

Additionally, more information will be helpful. What format are your source tables in? (ORC, Parquet, SequenceFiles, etc.) What version of Hive+Hadoop? Are you running Hive on Tez or Hive on MapReduce?

Comment: This is a query thats generated from Informatica tool so its like that, but now thats its generated, we can surely edit and fix it

Comment: Ah ok... that makes sense. I didn't know that `SELECT c1 ... GROUP BY c1` is equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT c1`. I'm not sure how well predicate push down and CBO are going to work in your case. My recommendation is to decompose the query into it's individual parts, and simplify the query by hand, then run `EXPLAIN` on both queries to examine the query plan. That might yield some insights. Then you can run `EXPLAIN` on the whole query also to look for more insights. But as of right now, we need more information to be able to figure out how to "fix" the query.